# java.io.IOException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream while Reading xls file from S3

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, amazon-s3, apache-poi

I am trying to read xls File from S3. However, I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

My code looks like this:

```
       public Object readFile() {
    String fileName = "<file_name_with_path";

    S3Object object = this.s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName));
    InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();
    // Process the objectData stream.

    InputStream targetStream = null;



    try {
        String reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(object.getObjectContent()))
            .lines()
            .parallel()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

        targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(reader.getBytes());
        //          objectData.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        //          Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(targetStream);
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(targetStream);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        for (Row row: sheet) // iteration over row using for each loop
        {
            for (Cell cell: row) // iteration over cell using for each loop
            {
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(checkNull(cell)));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The error is thrown at this line :

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

Any idea on what is the mistake I might be making?

Comment: The error tells pretty clear that your `InputStream file` was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream. But those two are the only two formats `apache poi` is able to handle. OLE2 = binary `BIFF` format `*.xls` or OOXML = Office Open XML format `*.xlsx`. So what exactly does `this.amazonS3ClientService.readData(fileName);` return?

Comment: Sorry, I made the edits to the code. The contents of this method this.amazonS3ClientService.readData(fileName)I have added to the code in the question.

Comment: As said, `InputStream` for `WorkbookFactory` must be either an OLE2 stream or an OOXML stream. Both are binary streams. None of them can be created using a `Reader` as they are no character streams.

Comment: `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(object.getObjectContent()))` will mangle the data - you should use the object.getObjectContent directly - eg `WorkbookFactory.create(object.getObjectContent())`

Comment: This works @PJFanning. Thank you!! You are a saviour.

Comment: Excel files are binary format and using a Reader will corrupt the data (Readers are for text format data - and not every byte combination is valid in text format) - if you want to buffer an InputStream, use BufferedInputStream.